# Measure page load time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I saw some other method of measure with using trace, but I just wonder this method measure correctly...

I overrided each execution of the following:

```
PreInit 
Init 
InitComplete 
PreLoad 
Load 
LoadComplete 
PreRender 
PreRenderComplete 
SaveStateComplete 
Unload
```

Then I store the time when the handler execute with using DateTime.Now.Tick...

At the end of Unload I will print out each of their execution time....

So the time above should be the time server spent to generate the page?

I am asking is because I notice some page took like 879ms in total above, but until my browser actually see the page is take few more seconds.

Those few more seconds should be the time that takes to download the page from server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's [a blog post](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/show-page-load-time/) that explains 2 ways of accomplishing this in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's time for the code to run and the time for the browser to get the response from the server and output it to the screen. You can measure the front-end work using a variety of measuring sites:

1. [Pingdom Tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/)
2. [WebWait](http://webwait.com/)
3. [Web page Test](http://www.webpagetest.org/)

To determine the timing for processing of the code, I would use the [`StopWatch` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) instead of using `DateTime`. DateTime is more precise to the decimal point, but less accurate. `StopWatch` is designed exactly for that and would be better to use to calculate the timing. Avoid calling it a lot though, as that itself will add overhead to the page processing. I would create a `new StopWatch()` then call Start at the very beginning, then call stop at the very end. Then spit out the elapsed time after.

- [StopWatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)
- [Precise Run Time Measurements with Stopwatch](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/testing/stopwatch-measure-precise.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

in global.asax

```
namespace aaaaa
{
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    private Stopwatch sw = null;

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sw != null)
        {
            sw.Stop();
            Response.Write("took " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds to generate this page");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking for overall time, why not just look at the time-taken value in your IIS logs?

The extra time in the browser could be a lot of things.  Fetching, Images, CSS, javascript files, javascript running in the page, and the client rendering of the HTML itself.  If you want to get a better feel for what is actually happening and when fire up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and then reload your page and look at what happened in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

At the very top of you .aspx page if you set the Trace flag it will give you a pretty good readout of how much each of the above events took without having to add any additional event handlers.  E.g.

```
<%@ Page Trace="true" Title=...
```

In your code behind, if there are any other events/functions you want to measure, you can add

```
Page.Trace("start of something interesting");
...
Page.Trace("end of something interesting");
```

And it will automatically measure the time in between the Page.Trace calls.